# Keyboard notification is not working on iPads with iOS 10+ when focusing the Texfield in WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, keyboard-events, wkwebview

I am working on a WKWebview iOS app. The keyboard notification is not calling methods to add the observer on iPads with iOS 10+. Not even in the simulator, when  focusing on the text field in the WKWebView.

Below is the code I wrote in `ViewDidLoad`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

This is being called on the iPhone but not on the iPad. I tried these lines on the different functions too, like `ViewWillAppear` and `ViewDidAppear`.

Comment: have u created seprate xib for iphone and ipad?? Do check  IBoutlet of your textfield is connected properly.

Comment: Actually I am working with Storyboard and the text field is loaded in the WKWEbview. Even the same code is working well on iPAd 2 with iOS 9

Comment: ok, try cleaning then rebuilding the project. Sometimes there are any dependencies which get loose. Close all instances of XCode , reopen project clean and build. It helps me most of the times.

Comment: Folks thanks for reply.
I just tried after resetting the iPad settings and worked fine

Comment: cool.. if cleaning or rebuilding does not works this is the third step i always take.. resetting iphone / iPad, when i am confident on my code. ;)

Comment: haha,,same here. I checked that on 4-5 devices and was working fine.

Comment: @luckyShubhra  Can you please suggest one thing more
I am facing another problem, I am using Bluetooth Scanner connected with iPad, Right? Now when the Scanner is connected the Keybords doesn;t appear on the screen, Right? Just the Suggestion bar with copy paste and hide button appears, Right?

Now when user clicks on that hide keyboard button the keyboard hides but the focus remain in the textfield, so after that on clicking the textfield it doesn't appear and even no Notification works in the code like UIKeyboardWillHideNotification etc. 

So How I can get the notifications in that case

Comment: Which wireless scanner r u using??

Comment: Currently I am testing with bluetooth keyboard and same issue is there,
Scanner is used by client, I think its Honeywell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147704/discussion-between-luckyshubhra-and-rahish).